# Overrride column name of a primefaces table in an exported CSV file using p:dataExporter

Tags: csv, jsf, primefaces, export-to-csv

I am using Primefaces p:dataExporter in order to export the data from the p:dataTable in a CSV file. I want to have a different header name for one of the table columns in my exported file. How can I do that since the preProcessor and postProcessor methods are used just for XLS and PDF? Should I create my own exporter?

Comment: Yes or try using PrimeFaces Extensions exporter or add 'pre/post' processing to the PrimeFaces dataexporter for CSV and provide a pull request. Or maybe the 'exportFunction' attribute can help.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices...

1. If you are using PrimeFaces [6.0.31, 6.1.17 or 6.2.4](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3642) or higher you can use the new "exportHeader" attribute on the column.

   `<p:column headerText="Test" exportHeader="My Exported Column Name">`
2. If you are not using one of those versions of PF or higher than you can create your own [customized exporter](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/customizedDocuments.xhtml).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Melloware. My version of primefaces is 6.1. And as far as I have seen those customized exporters could be used just for Excel and PDF exports. So, I cannot use one for a CSV export.

Comment: You are right the customized is only XLSX or PDF.  So you can either subscibe to ELITE and get the download or build from the Source Code in GitHub. It's all there for you to build the patched 6.1 JAR for yourself.